# How to count items in a Tasket in spring-batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a `Tasklet` and want to count the items processed. Then a common `StepExecutionListener` should be able to read those processed item count in `afterStep()`:

```
@Bean
public Step myStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step2")
            .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                @Override
                public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                    int items = dao.deleteItems(); //how to pass these items to a StepExecutionListener?
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }
            })
            .build();


@Component
public class MyListener extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {
    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        long items = stepExecution.getWriteCount();
        return super.afterStep(stepExecution);
    }
}
```

How can I get the processed items into the `stepExecution` within the tasklet?

Comment: This [Tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) might help you.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do that:

- Increment the write count from the `StepContribution` with `contribution.incrementWriteCount(items);`
- Set the write count from the `StepExecution`. You can access the `StepExecution` from the current `ChunkContext`. You need to call [`getStepContext()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/ChunkContext.html#getStepContext--) to retrieve the `StepContext`, then call [`getStepExecution()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/StepContext.html#getStepExecution--) to retrieve the `StepExecution` and finally, you can set the write count with [`setWriteCount(writeCount)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#setWriteCount-int-).

A sample code would be:

```
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    int items = dao.deleteItems();
    contribution.incrementWriteCount(items);
    // OR: chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setWriteCount(items);
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a tasklet and not a chunk, the classic "read/process/write" does not apply. If you want to transfer a value from your step execution to a stepExecutionListener *on the same* step, then simply put a key/value in your stepExecutionContext:

```
   int items=dao.deleteItems();
   chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().putInt("MYKEY", items);
```

In your StepExecutionListener afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) method:

```
ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
int items = executionContext.getInt("MYKEY");
```